# how can i display different views based on authentication ? asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Like for example when a user vists the index page he sees content that is different from the content that a logged in user sees.

How can i achieve this, does this require some kind of annotation or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried _Layout view or partial views?

Comment: But how are they related to it ? Shouldn't this routing be the responsibility of controller action ?

Comment: If you use mvc authentication you can decide what should be shown in your view,because the User object is access able every where in your view and if you write @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in a if condition you can decide what to show in view.You can use it in every view.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to handle this...

If you want to handle it in the controller or the view its up to you.
Ideally I would hazard a guess the choice depends on what you want to display or not display  as the case may be.

If you handle it in the controller....

```
Function Index()As ActionResult
  If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
    ' Logged in is TRUE
    Return View(LoggedInUserContentModel)
  Else
    ' Logged in is FALSE
    Return View(SiteGuestUserContentModel)
  End If
End Function
```

If you handle it in the View....
DIRECTLY Showing page content

```
<% If Request.IsAuthenticated Then %>
  <!-- User is Logged In -->
  Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></b>!
  [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")%> ]
<% Else %>
  <!-- User is NOT Logged In -->
  Welcome <b>Guest</b> please login!
  [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")%> ]
<% End If %>
```

You may optionally choose not to directly show content embedded on the page itself but may choose to show content retrieved from within a ChildAction
(this would be similar to showing it in a UserControl using the old non MVC style of web design as opposed to directly placing the content on the web page)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of handling it is to use the RedirectToAction in your controller method.

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "AuthenticatedController")
    Else
        Return View()
    End If
End Function
```